# HBASE (Importing data)

Tags: hadoop, import, hbase

I am new to hadoop and Hbase. I have data like this

CustID, Trait, Count
ABC,  iav, 3
ABC, xyz, 3
BCD,iav,4
BCD,ter,4

and I want to read this data in through API, bulk import (record size over 800 Mil) or from PIG and have data presented in Hbase as (Transposed)

CustId, iav, xyz, ter
ABC,    3,   3,   NULL
BCD,    4,   NULL, 4

Data is in HDFS. How do I go about doing this. I would appreciate your guidance on this. Being new I haven't been able to do much. I am mostly PIG and HIve kind of a person.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://mikaelsitruk.wordpress.com/2011/09/15/pig-and-hbase-integration/)

The Hadoop ecosystem contains a lot of sub project. Hbase and Pig are just some of them.

Hbase is the Hadoop database, allowing to manage your data in a table way more than in a file way.

Pig is a scripting language that will generate on the fly map reduce job to get the data you need. It is very compact compared to hand writing map reduce job.